# Imagem de fundo dinamicamente

Tags: angularjs, ionic, sqlite, apache-cordova, scss

Tenho uma lista de produtos, clicando em algum deles, redireciona para outra página mostrando apenas o conteúdo desse item. Eu recebo a Imagem, mas gostaria que ela ficasse como plano de fundo, ou seja: vai mostrar a mesma imagem em tamanho grande, e com texto e etc escrito por cima. Tem como a partir do meu HTML eu definir a imagem como background?  Pois para receber ela estou usando  `<img src="{{produto.nom_pathimagem}}" class="bgimage" >`. Logo não posso definir um valor padrão em scss.  Obrigado a qualquer ajuda :D

Answer (score -1):

Declare em style.
Exemplo:

```
<div style="background-image:url('{{ produto.nom_pathimagem }}')"></div>
```

;)

Comment: não funcinou.  Em meu caminho no banco de dados para receber as imagens está:    `assets/imgs/id-1.png`     .  Então no html estou usando  `<img src="{{produto.nom_pathimagem}}" class="bgimage" >`.   Tentei sua solução mas não apareceu nada. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: verificou no console?

Comment: recebo isso:  WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value background-image:url('assets/imgs/id-1.png') (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Comment: É possível através de scss eu definir o background-image dinamicamente?

Comment: No angular 6.1 rodando em localhost aqui funcionou. tente usar ng-style em vez de style.

Comment: ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/{{ produto.nom_pathimagem }})'}"

Comment: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{'background-image':'url(/assets/imgs/id-1.png)'}'        usei `<div ngStyle="{'background-image':'url(/{{ produto.nom_pathimagem }})'}"></div>`